# Dealing with model object updates and synchronizing associated tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

​Hello, I am building a Ruby on Rails cashflow app where the "balance" field in the "accounts" table will be updated based on the "amount" field in the "incomes" table.

How should I deal with Income object updates (when "amount" is changed), so that the "balance" field in "accounts" is updated properly (first decreased by the previous "amount" of the "Income" and then updated with new "amount")?

Is it a good practice to use callbacks in the "Income" model and ActiveModel::Dirty methods such as "income.amount_was" to get the previous value?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to create a service object, instead of directly updating the `Income#amount` via `income.update` in the controller. Updating another model inside some other model's callback IMO increases coupling and debugging complexity as the responsibility bleeds outside its own.

For example, create a `IncomeUpdaterService` that does this:

```rb
class IncomeUpdaterService
  def initialize(income)
    @income = income
    @account = ... # Depends on how they are connected
  end

  def update(params)
    # DB Transaction
    # You might want to lock the Account record
    ...
    update_balance(params.amount) if params.amount
    ...
    # DB Transaction Commit
  end
  
  private

  def update_balance(new_amount)
    prev_amount = @income.amount
    balance_adjustment = new_amount - prev_amount
    @account.balance += balance_adjustment
    # I think theres a @account.increment(:balance, balance_adjustment)
    # to avoid race condition instead of locking the record, but not sure
    # if it's a good practice to use. From what I remember there's some
    # kind of warning for using it.
    @account.save
  end
end
```

(For the self projecting master developers out there. Just wrote this quickly just to put it out there, don't be too hypercritical on this code as this is just an example and start insulting me, but feel free to suggest some improvements.)